# Framer-Motion: How to Animate gradientTransform?

Tags: svg, linear-gradients, framer-motion

I'm using the framer-motion library in React. I have a `<motion.linearGradient>` component.

I'm wondering how do I animate the `gradientTransform` property?

I'd like to do something like `gradientTransform: "rotate(90)"` and animate rotating the gradient between 0 degrees and 90 degrees.

I'm not sure how to do that because gradientTransform's value is a string and none of the solutions I've tried yet have worked.

Comment: use SMIL to animate it.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity sake~

https://github.com/KirdesMF created this PR: https://github.com/framer/motion/pull/1151 to enable animation of linear gradients.

I don't know what release it was a part of, but it was between 4.1.17 and 4.1.18

I created a code sandbox demo you can play around with: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animating-linear-gradient-7ibrt?file=/src/App.tsx